# Using a subquery in 'FROM' in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I would like to know how I can use a subquery in FROM clause using gorm. It would look like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT foo.*
  FROM foo
  WHERE bar = "baz"
) AS t1
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

I have built the subquery using golang:

```
db.Model(Foo{}).Where("bar = ?", "baz")
```

But how can I use this as a subquery in `FROM`?

If there is a method that turns a gorm query into a SQL string, then I can simply plug that string into a raw SQL. But there does not seem to be such method. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `QueryExpr`, refer

https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#SubQuery

> db.Where("amount > ?",
> DB.Table("orders").Select("AVG(amount)").Where("state = ?",
> "paid").QueryExpr()).Find(&orders)

Which generate SQL

> SELECT * FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
> (amount > (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM "orders"  WHERE (state = 'paid')));

Comment: `QueryExpr` returns `*expr`. Any suggestions on how to plug that value in `FROM`? Also, the link does not work because there is no 'subquery' section in the doc.

Comment: is `DB` equivalent to `gorm.DB`. I am not able to find `QueryExpr()` func in my library

Comment: @SumitAgarwal I have the same question. Using `gorm.DB` there won't work because the receiver isn't a pointer. And declaring a `var DB *gorm.DB` doesn't work either because then it's trying to call `Table` on a nil pointer. Definitely not obvious what the solution is, but I'm still looking..

Comment: It looks like you can just use `db`, or whatever variable is your top-level `*gorm.DB`. I think the uppercase `DB` is a typo.

Answer (score 9):

Also you can do it with join on a subquery

```
subQuery := db.
    Select("foo.*").
    Table("foo").
    Where("bar = ?", "baz").
    SubQuery()

db.
    Select("t1.*").
    Join("INNER JOIN ? AS t1 ON t1.id = foo.id", subQuery).
    Where("t1.id = ?", 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Author didn't use any "JOIN" in his SQL.

I didn't find any ORM way, but `db.Raw` works.

```
subQuery := db.
    Select("foo.*").
    Table("foo").
    Where("bar = ?", "baz").
    SubQuery()

db.Raw("SELECT * FROM ? as t1 WHERE t1.id=?", subQuery, 1).Find(&rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI – Jinzhu's method doesn't work

I have subqueries working using this method...

```golang
var somevalue = 1
row := db.Select("something").Table("first_table").Where("exists(?)", db.Select("a_relationship_to_something").Model(&SecondTable{}).Where("id = ?", somevalue).QueryExpr()).Row()
var result string
row.Scan(&result)
```

I've tested this with `row()`, `rows()`, `first()`, and `find()`. You can also use both `.Table()` and `.Model()` interchangeably as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

also could be used in join

```
subQuery:=db.Find(&subTable).QueryExpr()

db.
Table("table").
Select("*").
Join("join (?) as t1 on t1.id==table.id", //<---round brackets for multiple rows
subQuery).
Find(&Rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

while i used "db.Select("*").Joins("?", subQuery)" to query, i got "select * from `` (subquery)" whitch is a wrong sql.
I should use 'db.Select("*").Table(" ").Joins("?", subQuery)'.

```
subQuery := db.
    Select("foo.*").
    Table("foo").
    Where("bar = ?", "bar")
db := db.
    Select("*").
    Table(" "). // gorm will give you the origin input instead of "``"
    Joins("? as t1", subQuery.QueryExpr()).
    Where("t1.id = ?", 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved this issue by creating a package for more flexibility: https://github.com/loeffel-io/sql

```
subquery := sql.Create().
    Select(true, "purchases.*").
    Select(true, "...").
    From(true, "purchases").
    Join(true, "transactions ON transactions.purchase_id=purchases.id")

query := sql.Create().Select(true, "*").
    From(true, "(?) purchases", gorm.Expr(subquery.GetSQL(), subquery.GetValues()...)).
    Join(true, "transactions ON transactions.id=purchases.last_transaction_id")

db.
    Raw(query.GetSQL(), query.GetValues()...).
    Offset(...).
    Limit(...).
    Order(...).
    Unscoped().
    Find(&purchases).
    Error
```